# Calcular Valor das colunas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho duas tabelas `BMV_PEDIDO` e `BMV_PEDIDOITEM` e gostaria da soma total do valor dos pedidos feitos em determinada data. Atualmente faço isso pedido por pedito, ou seja, replico esse código 70x.

Gostaria que minha consulta retornasse todos.

Segue o *script* atual:

```
SELECT p.ST_FRETE, SUM(i.NR_QTDE * i.VL_UNITARIO * i.NR_TAXACONVERSAO) 
FROM BMV_PEDIDOITEM i 
INNER JOIN BMV_PEDIDO p ON p.ID_PEDIDO = i.ID_PEDIDO 
WHERE p.ID_PEDIDO IN (45752)
GROUP BY p.ST_FRETE
```

Comment: p.ID_PEDIDO in( 45752) ? é quando você tiver 1000 pedidos vai repetir 1000 vezes o mesmo código?

Comment: @JuniorTorres: Além da "soma total do valor dos pedidos feitos em determinada data", necessita também que os pedidos da data sejam listados? Ou somente o valor total, sem linhas de detalhe?

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que seja isso:

```
select 
 p.ST_FRETE, 
 SUM(i.NR_QTDE * i.VL_UNITARIO * i.NR_TAXACONVERSAO) as valortotal
from BMV_PEDIDOITEM i 
inner join BMV_PEDIDO p on p.ID_PEDIDO = i.ID_PEDIDO 
--where p.ID_PEDIDO in( 45752) 
where p.datapedido between '2016-01-01' and '2016-03-31'  
group by p.ST_FRETE
```

Comment: Não amigo, isso ele me retorna a soma de todos.
Gostaria da soma de cada pedido;

Comment: Você tem o seu pedido e seus itens do pedido e quando você faz o “inner join” você está trazendo os itens de um pedido especifico, e somando os totais, se você não informar o id do pedido ele vai calcular de todos os pedidos.

Comment: Conforme você descreve acima, você quer a soma total do valor dos pedidos feitos em determinada data. Nesse caso essa query que o @itasouza escreveu resolveria, Agora se você quer por pedido ai precisa acrescentar o número do pedido na cláusula WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

> *gostaria da soma total do valor dos pedidos feitos em determinada data*

Nesse caso não é necessário o uso da cláusula GROUP BY. Eis sugestão de código:

```
-- código #2
SELECT sum(I.NR_QTDE * I.VL_UNITARIO * I.NR_TAXACONVERSAO) as totalPEDIDO
  from BMV_PEDIDOITEM as I 
       inner join BMV_PEDIDO as P on P.ID_PEDIDO = I.ID_PEDIDO
  where P.colunadatapedido = ...
```

---

Mas se o objetivo for obter a soma pedido a pedido, me parece que falta o código do pedido no resultado.

```
-- código #1
SELECT P.ID_PEDIDO,
       sum(I.NR_QTDE * I.VL_UNITARIO * I.NR_TAXACONVERSAO) as soma_ITENS_PEDIDO
  from BMV_PEDIDOITEM as I 
       inner join BMV_PEDIDO as P on P.ID_PEDIDO = I.ID_PEDIDO
  where P.colunadatapedido = ...
  group by P.ID_PEDIDO;
```